# iPhone X Home Bar Hide + other hiddens

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently developing an application that will be used in dark conditions.

I require the application to hide the home bar after launch, as well as not appearing after a touch gesture. I'd require it only to show with attempts to genuinely bring up the home bar.

I've tried

```
-(BOOL)prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Which works great. However, after a touch gesture it re-appears.

I need a solution that will also allow the App to be accepted into the store.

Whilst I'm at it, I require it to also stop push notifications from messages, whatsapp or any notifications that would show through with light.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards.